# Building a jar file which contains YAML files from Github

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, yaml

I am fairly new to java I have a requirement where I need to build a jar file. This jar file will contain a couple of YAML files and these YAML files need to be downloaded from GitHub everytime the jar builds.

I am not able to find a way to download these files and include them in the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some "download" plugin like [this](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task). (It supports authentication)

```
plugins {
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "4.1.0"
}
```

Now to download the file(s):

```
task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src 'http://www.example.com/index.yaml'
    dest buildDir
}
```

Next define a dependency of this task like:

```
jar.dependsOn downloadFile
```